# Regular Expression containing letters and spaces in specified fashion

Tags: regex

I am working on a text processing Api in java. I need to match the strings which are:

1. **At least 8 characters in length.**
2. **Should only contain uppercase letters, lowercase letters or spaces.**
3. **Spaces should not be present in between the letters. They can however be leading or trailing. The String can also contain only spaces which are at least 8.**

> Regular expression which I tried but failed:
>
> 1. `^\s*[a-zA-Z]{8,}\s*$`

Demo of my tries in [here](https://regex101.com/r/WBbtyb/1/).

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: It would be much easier to check (1) with Java code. Have you considered that?

Comment: Ya!You're right @Sweeper. But I wanted a regex that meets all the three requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your result:

`^(?=.{8,}) *[a-zA-Z]* *$`

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> 1. `^` - denotes start of the test String.
> 2. `(?=)` - Positive lookahead.
> 3. `.{8,}` - any character other than newline with length at least 8.
> 4. `*` - 0 or more spaces in order to match the leading spaces.(`\s` is avoided)
> 5. `[a-zA-Z]*` - 0 or more letters (uppercase or lowercase). (You can use `[a-z]*` along with `i`(case insensitive) flag. Although, there will be **no effect** on performance.)
> 6. `*` - 0 or more spaces in order to match the trailing spaces.(`\s` is avoided)
> 7. `$` -  denotes end of the test String.

Above regex [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WBbtyb/2).

Comment: It serves my purpose.Thanks.Why you put **4** and **6** point which you mentioned in your explanation of regex?